# Better/More Portable Method of Defining PI in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, math, constants, angle

Currently in one my scientific computation codes I have the following:

```
//Include M_PI constant
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
//Needed for square root function.
#include <math.h>
```

This works... on Linux at least... I have not tested it for C compilers on all platforms.  However, when surveying some older Fortran codes, I recently came across this seemingly clever way of defining pi in another code (not my own):

```
<angle in deg.>*8.0d0 * datan(1.0d0) / 360.0d0
```

Of course this is perfectly feasible in C, right?  So I could define my conversion function something like:

```
inline double DegToRad(const double A)
{
   return A * atan(1.0) / 45.0;
}
```

Which approach is more portable?  Are there any numeric (e.g. rounding) considerations that would merit using one approach over another?

I do like that the M_PI constants make the code more readable.  Of course, I could happily just assign my own PI constant using the above approach.

What is considered best practice in C/C++ codes that are going to be targeted at multiple platforms (Windows, Linux, etc.)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't minimize the readability issue; personally, I'd do something like this:

```
#ifndef M_PI
// Source: http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~huberty/math5337/groupe/digits.html
#define M_PI 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406 
#endif

#define DEG_TO_RAD (M_PI/180.0)
#define RAD_TO_DEG (180.0/M_PI)
```

and then declare

```
inline double DegToRad(const double deg) {
   return deg * DEG_TO_RAD;
}

inline double RadToDeg(const double rad) {
   return rad * RAD_TO_DEG;
}
```

This is probably not going to be any more or less portable (both `atan` and `M_PI` are standard in both C and C++).  However it will be more readable than using `atan` and depending on your compiler's optimization settings, may save you a costly trig function call.

**UPDATE**:  It looks like M_PI isn't as standard as I thought.  Inclusion of the `#ifndef` above should take care of the instances where it's not available.

Comment: Okay, gotcha.... I didn't know if M_PI was exclusive to GNU or certain platforms... I've seen stranger things...

Comment: If you come across an older compiler which isn't standards compliant you can simply define your own `M_PI`, bracketing it with a `#ifndef M_PI` ... `#endif`

Comment: `M_PI` is a POSIX-ism.  It's available on most platforms, but not guaranteed to exist by the C standard.

Comment: Re Stephen Canon, specifically SUSv2 / Unix98: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xsh/math.h.html

Comment: I think #define DEG_TO_RAD (M_PI/180.0) would be better, for otherwise someone who uses 1.0/DEG_TO_RAD would be disappointed.

Answer (score 1):

#### Universal Solution

One possible way is to use a macro:

```cpp
#define PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028L
#define DEG_TO_RAD(...) ((__VA_ARGS__) * (PI / 180))
// note: write DEG_TO_RAD(x) in C89
```

This works in any version of C and C++. The amount of digits used here is *exactly* enough for the *binary128* floating-point format.
This is important because `long double` could be a 128-bit number.

The `M_PI` macro is not portable and you should avoid using it.
You can just as well define your own macro, which is guaranteed to exist on all platforms.

#### Non-macro pi definitions

```cpp
// C23 / C++11 compatible constants.
// Ideally, make these inline in C++17 to avoid possibly ODR violations.
// In C89/C++98, these could be declared as static const instead.
constexpr long double pil = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028L;
constexpr double pi = (double) pil;
constexpr float pif = (float) pi;
```

```cpp
// C++17 solution using constrained variable template
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, int> = 0>
inline constexpr T pi_v = T(3.1415926535897932384626433832795028L);

// note: this is unnecessary in C++20 thanks to std::numbers::pi in <numbers>
```

#### Degrees to radians

```cpp
// C++20 using constraints and the new numeric constants
#include <numbers>

template <std::floating_point T>
T deg_to_rad(T x) {
    return x * std::numbers::pi_v<T>;
}
```

```cpp
// C++17, see the variable template above
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T, int> = 0>
T deg_to_rad(T x) {
    return x * pi_v<T>;
}
```

```cpp
// C11 using generic selection
float deg_to_radf(float x) { return x * (pif / 180); }
// ...
#define deg_to_rad(...) _Generic((__VA_ARGS__), \
    float: deg_to_radf,                         \
    double: deg_to_rad,                         \
    long double: deg_to_radl)(__VA_ARGS__)
```